# How to enable lanman workstation setting in group policy using PowerShell or command line?

Tags: batch

Is there any PowerShell or command line which can enable the enable insecure guest logons in administrative templates\network\lanman workstation in individual computer?
[image]

After adding registry but no change in the group policy.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

See
[Enable insecure guest logons](https://admx.help/?Category=Windows_10_2016&Policy=Microsoft.Policies.LanmanWorkstation::Pol_EnableInsecureGuestLogons):

> This policy setting determines if the SMB client will allow insecure
> guest logons to an SMB server.
>
> If you enable this policy setting or if you do not configure this
> policy setting, the SMB client will allow insecure guest logons.
>
> If you disable this policy setting, the SMB client will reject
> insecure guest logons.

| Registry Hive | HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE |
| --- | --- |
| Registry Path | Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\LanmanWorkstation |
| Value Name | AllowInsecureGuestAuth |
| Value Type | REG_DWORD |
| Enabled Value | 1 |
| Disabled Value | 0 |

You may use the
[reg add command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/reg-add)
to set this value in the registry.

Comment: I added the REGISTRY but the GP did not change. See captured screen !

Comment: Did you reboot?